# Windows 7 installation missing dvd/cd drivers

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am trying to install windows 7 from dvd but I get the error that the drivers for the dvd/cd are missing...

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

I've tried the following without luck:

- Removed the dvd drive
- Burned the installation dvd as an image to a usb stick
- burned the iso to a new dvd using 1x speed

Comment: What kind of optical drive do you have?

Comment: an LG dvd/cd writer

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it has to do with your AHCI settings for your optical drive. Switching back to IDE mode has fixed it for me.

Comment: It can also be a corrupt burn of the DVD or a corrupt source file that was used to make the DVD.

Comment: how can I check this?